# PHP - in URL replacing space with + sign and 301-forward to + sign version

Tags: php, redirect

In PHP I have this URL which is valid:

```
http://example.net/dir/valid+page/
```

But some people replace + with space, ie. they try to access this URL instead:

```
http://example.net/dir/valid page/
```

Here, I think, space is replaced with %20 in the URL in browser.

My question is: how to detect if there is a space in this URL (or, probably better, in the part after /dir/) and if so, 301-redirect user to the version with the + instead?

I have this part of code, but the first line is missing:

```
if(??space_in_/valid page/_url??)
{
header('HTTP 1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
header("http://example.net/dir/valid+page/");
exit;
}
```

Comment: While spaces in the URL are *valid*, they can also be quite troublesome. Consider changing your URL structure to incorporate hyphens or underscores instead of spaces. And `header("Location: http://example.net/dir/valid+page/");` is a valid way to redirect (note the *Location:* in the `header()`

Comment: Yes, that's why I try to redirect 301 to the + version instead of space.

Answer (score 1):

Get the path of the URL, and use `preg_match` to check if there is a space in the path.

```
$url = 'http://example.net/dir/valid page/';

if (preg_match ('/ /', parse_url ($url, PHP_URL_PATH))) {
    header ('HTTP 1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
    header ('Location: http://example.net/dir/valid+page/');
    exit;
}
```

Comment: I was thinking about similar, but maybe it's possible to only check if a space is in the /dir/vaild page/ part? Instead of the whole URL?

Answer (score 0):

These are two different URLs you're talking about. `http://example.net/dir/valid+page/` will give you your page, and `http://example.net/dir/valid page/` will give you a 404 error. Putting code in the page won't help, because it never sees the invalid requests.

If you really feel you want to address this *particular* typo, you need to do so in your web server configuration. For Apache, you would add this:

```
Redirect permanent /dir/valid%20page/ http://example.net/dir/valid+page/
```